# Can concurrent value modification impact single select in PostgreSQL 9.1?

Tags: sql, postgresql, transaction-isolation

Consider the following query executed in PostgreSQL 9.1 (or 9.2):

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar = true
```

Suppose it's a fairly long running query (e.g. taking a minute).

If at the start of the query there are 5 million records for which `bar = true` holds, and during this query in another transaction there are rows added and removed in the `foo` table, and for some existing rows updates are made to the `bar` field.

Will any of this affect the outcome of the above shown select query?

I know about transaction-isolation and visibility between separate statements in a single transaction, but what about a single statement that's running?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No.
Due to the MVCC model only tuples that are visible at *query* start will be used in a single `SELECT`. Details in the manual [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/transaction-iso.html#XACT-READ-COMMITTED):

> Read Committed is the default isolation level in PostgreSQL. When a
>   transaction uses this isolation level, a SELECT query (without a FOR
>   UPDATE/SHARE clause) sees only data committed before the query began;
>   **it never sees either uncommitted data or changes committed during
>   query execution by concurrent transactions**. In effect, a SELECT query
>   sees a snapshot of the database as of the instant the query begins to
>   run. However, SELECT does see the effects of previous updates executed
>   within its own transaction, even though they are not yet committed.
>   Also note that two successive SELECT commands can see different data,
>   even though they are within a single transaction, if other
>   transactions commit changes during execution of the first SELECT.

Emphasis mine.

Answer (score 5):

The query will be a read-consistent view of the data as of the start of the query. In Postgresql, the documentation on Multi-Version Concurrency Control (MVCC) explains how it is done (multiple versions of a record exist in the table). In Oracle, the Sequence Change Number (SCN) is used along with "before-images" of modified data. Here is an old doc, [Transaction Processing in Postgresql](http://www.postgresql.org/files/developer/transactions.pdf), with the section "non-overwriting storage management". But take a look at MVCC.

Or read the chapter on [MVCC](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/mvcc-intro.html) in the Postgresql doc